# apache: redirect only 404 error messages to a different log file in httpd.conf

Tags: apache

After a bit of searching, I couldn't find a way to redirect only 404 specific error messages to a different log file(not error_log). Please let me know if there is way to achieve this. Quick help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3):

The [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive has an `env=` parameter that you can add to the end. You can then set that env variable using mod_rewrite. So in your server/vhost config, you'd have something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# exclude directory index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.(php|html?)$
# exlcude auto-index of directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# if the request is not a file, directory, or symlink
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# set the "notfound" environment variable
RewriteRule ^ - [E=notfound:true,L]

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/404-requests.log common env=notfound
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/requests.log common env=!notfound
```

So the custom log file `/var/log/apache2/404-requests.log` only gets logged to when the environment variable `notfound` is set, and the log file `/var/log/apache2/requests.log` only gets logged to for everything else. The auto indexing and directory indexing is a little hokey so that's why you need to exclude those from the `notfound` set of conditions.

Comment: should i put this under directory tag in httpd.conf?

Comment: @Iowa you can, if you want the 404/logging stuff to only get applied to requests for a specific directory

Comment: I tried the above solution, but it doesnt seem to work. Quick help anyone?